# Two questions on dimensions of affine algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is two exercises from An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry:

> 1. Show that dimension is an invariant of the isomorphism class of a variety.

It intuitively makes sense, but the dimension I've seen so far is defined as the longest possible chain of sub-variants. It makes sense that the isomorphism should preserve the inclusion relations of all the sub-variants so that the length of the chains should be the same, preserved by the isomorphism. But I'm not sure how to precisely formulate this.

> A similar question: Show that $X \rightarrow Y$ is a surjective morhpsm of affine algebraic varieties, then the dimension of $X$ is at least as large as the dimension of $Y$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The argument you describe is correct. Show that any isomorphism induces an order-preserving bijection on the poset of subvarieties.

Comment: Do you know that the dimension of an (irreducible) variety $X$ is equal to the transcendence degree of its function field? That really helps with the second question.

Comment: @Hoot Sorry I haven't learned what this is yet. I've looked up but the concepts are not cooked up well enough to understand how it could be used for the second question...A detailed explanation will be super helpful! :)

Comment: She must have something else in mind, then. I'll take a look at the book later.